# How to unit test Zend Console Prompt. Unit test currently waits for user response

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I am using zend 2.2 and zend/console to create cli script. The script prompts a user to enter information like name or email address with the following code

```
$name = Line::prompt('Enter Name: ', false, 100);
```

This works fine when user is using script.

My problem is trying to unit test this. At this moment when i call dispatch in unit test it just hangs and waits for a user to enter a response. Obviously this is a problem.

My code is:

```
public function testCliScript()
{   
    $consoleMock = $this->getConsoleMock();
    $consoleMock->expects($this->any())->method('writeLine');

    $this->dispatch('run cli--name=test --email=test@example.com');
}
```

Which eventually calls

```
protected function getName()
{
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
    $nameOk = !empty($name);

    while (!$nameOk) {
        $nameOk = false;
        $name = Line::prompt('Enter Name: ', false, 100);
        // tie into filter
        if (strlen($name) < 1) {
            $this->getConsole()->writeLine('Name is Too Short');
            continue;
        }

        $nameOk = true;
    };


    return $name;
}
```

If anyone has any advice as to how to test this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the main arguments for the [Dipendency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle): testability.

Your prompt object is a hard dependency of your SUT thus, to properly test the SUT, you need to decouple the two.

An example using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) via the constructor:

```
// uses omitted for brevity
class SomeController extends AbstractConsoleController
{
    protected $namePrompt;

    public function __construct(PromptInterface $namePrompt)
    {
        $this->namePrompt = $namePrompt;
    }

    protected function getName()
    {
        // etc etc
        $name = $this->namePrompt->show();

    }
}
```

so you can inject a prompt mock in your test:

```
// uses omitted for brevity
class SomeControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $controller;

    protected $namePromptMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        // etc etc
        $this->namePromptMock = $this->getMock(PromptInterface::class);
        $this->controller     = new SomeController($this->namePromptMock);
        // etc etc
    }

    public function testSomeAction()
    {
        $this->namePromptMock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
                             ->method('show')
                             ->willReturn('a fake name');

        // dispatch, assertions on the response, etc etc
    }
}
```

There are other ways you can achieve dependency inversion, i.e. for this very case the controller may need a whole bunch of prompts, so instead of injecting every single prompt instance (which is inconvenient and ugly) you could use a small plugin manager as a service locator, or use some kind of factory, and you could easily mock such abstraction so that it just returns prompt mocks when asked.